# Lots of Explore issues

Tags: neovim, netrw

I've been using [Neo]vim for a few months now with a number of plugins.  One I decided to use was the built in `:Explore` for my file-browsing needs.

I am having some serious issues with `Explore` and need some help in resolving (or tell me if it is normal).

Note that the below issues happen in both `vim` and `Neovim`.

### **Ghost Buffers opening based on text clicked**

With mouse-mode enabled, using `:Vex` to open vertical explore and the *focus of the window is in the Explorer window*, if I use the mouse to click into a window/buffer of an already opened file and I click a line of code:

1. A new blank buffer opens.
2. The name of the buffer is the contents of the line I entered, in the form of `^Irun.Proxy()` (the line of code I clicked on had `run.Proxy()`.
3. The Explore window now is blank/empty with no history.

Resolution is to close the empty buffer (which, without a plugin to close the buffer without closing the window is a PITA), close the window for the Explorer, re-open Explorer (and split, again, if I had to close the window).

Very annoying.

### **Lanching `:Vex` from a buffer of a sub-directory opens invalid file**

This is not repeatable all the time...  But it does happen.

Launch `vim` from a project root folder, like:

```
cd ~/code/projectA/
vim
```

Now, open a file from a sub-directory:

```
:e sub-folder/file.go
```

Now launch `:Vex` and Explorer starts from that sub-directory because the current buffer is locates in `sub-folder/`.  Ok, not a big issue.  I select `..` in Explorer to backup to the project root.

Here's the issue: from this same `:Vex` window, if I open a file now at the project root, say `main.go`, what opens is a buffer to a file located at `sub-folder/main.go` instead of the file I selected in Explorer.  this buffer is blank.

BUT... if I close that buffer, change focus back to Explorer and select `main.go` *again*, now the correct file opens in a buffer.

Very annoying.

### Explorer inconsistent in keeping sub-folders open

Say I have `:Vex` open with 3 sub-folders open.  Once I switch to a buffer and edit/save a file, if I switch back to the existing `:Vex` that I still have open and select any other sub-folder:

1. The last sub-folder I opened collapses.  Often times, it is even the sub-folder I am in and I want to open yet a deeper sub-folder.
2. The sub-folder I selected does not open.

What happens is I have to re-open the sub-folders I previously had opened.  But, not all.  Some reopen expanded.

I have no found any way to have Explore retain its own state of open folders, let me switch to Explorer and *explore further* down the directory tree, without it collapsing everything else.

Very annoying.

#### Summary

Those are the biggest issues I have with Explore and it is seriously affecting my `vim mojo`.

Last week I was code-pairing with a colleague and it horribly apparent how messed up this is.  I've been getting so used to working around this issues that when he saw all of these issues, he was so turned off from ever trying vim in the future.  "I heard vim was pretty good; but wow, that's horrible man.  I couldn't stand it."

Please tell me if this is common, in which case I'll switch to Nerdtree or alike.  Or, if this is just my setup.  In which case, how I would I debug?

Using latest versions of vim and neovim from Homebrew.

Comment: The default file explorer is indeed buggy (and from what I've read it has more or less always been). Tim pope wrote the [vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar) plugin to improve it a little bit but it's still not perfect (I'm really not sure it would solve your problems). About Nerdtree, I used it, but it also have some annoying bugs (some buffers which doesn't close when they should and this kind of stuff). I would recommend to get used to functions like `:find`, `:e`, `:buffers` to get ride of file explorers. Some will also advise to use fuzzy finders (but I'm not of these ones).

Comment: thanks @statox! yeah, I've spent hours disabling most of my plugins and trying different plugins in hopes that it was one of my plugins.  but it's good (and bad) to hear that it is very buggy. that's annoying and basically is turning me off of vim: I have to do a lot of code discovery in my job, which I work best by visualizing the directory tree and naming conventions of the group of files.  Hence, `:Vex` and keeping it open with about a dozen buffers in another split view (sometimes 4 splits at once in a 2x2 pattern).

Comment: Well @eduncan911 I understand that, I also was used to the "traditional file explorer view" with your directory and your files but really it is just a question of habit: I got used to navigate in my file in another way and now it's just not a problem anymore (Still I've been using Nerdtree for something like a year so it took time to make the change). In my opinion Vim provides a many useful and efficient features that it is worth getting used to another way to browse your files :-)

Comment: Also I think this is a relevant article: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer ](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)

Comment: Can all this be reproduced with no .vimrc file, no plugins etc? (It's not clear from your comment about if you tried this)

Comment: I have built a minimal .Vimrc file with just some key changes, and reproduced the issues in the OP with no other plugins (vim, barebones).  So yes, it is reproducible.  If you'd like to take a look at my current .Vimrc, you can always see it here: https://github.com/eduncan911/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

- May I suggest that you try the latest version of netrw: v157b, which you may get from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW.
- Ghost buffers -- unable to duplicate
- Launching...
  Are you using the acd option?
  What netrw options are you using; in particular, what is g:netrw_keepdir?
  I've tried the procedure you mentioned five times now and never had the problem you had
- Explorer inconsistent...
  Tried with three subfolders open, all just one level in, did a split, edit, save, switch to netrw -- no unwanted closures occurred.
  Tried with with three nested subfolders open, did a split, edit, save, switch to netrw -- no unwanted closures occurred.